# redux and redux-saga UI action triggering multiple API actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Just trying to understand what the best practice is for a bunch of API calls to depend on a single UI action in `redux` and `redux-saga`. For instance

1. UI action `SELECTED_ITEM_CHANGE` gets triggered
2. Several API request actions get triggered: `DATA1_REQUEST`, `DATA2_REQUEST`, ..., `DATA10_REQUEST`
3. When `DATA1_REQUEST`, ... , `DATA10_REQUEST` get resolved, redux-saga sends a bunch of actions like `DATA1_SUCCESS` with data to resolve to the store. I got this part using `redux-saga` and I basically understand how to do it.

My question is, how do I get `DATA1_REQUEST`, ... , `DATA10_REQUEST` to get triggered when `SELECTED_ITEM_CHANGE` gets triggered? The dumb way is to just do it in the component that sends `SELECTED_ITEM_CHANGE` and just `dispatch` all of those actions along with the `SELECTED_ITEM_CHANGE` action, but this is not modular since the component should not be responsible for all those API calls. So who should handle this? I guess there's a couple options:

1. Make the action creator that dispatches `SELECTED_ITEM_CHANGE` also dispatch `DATA1_REQUEST`, ..., `DATA10_REQUEST`.
2. Make a saga that listens to `SELECTED_ITEM_CHANGE` and dispatch `DATA1_REQUEST`, ..., `DATA10_REQUEST`

I'm leaning towards the second, but I'm not very sure.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is your option, that's the whole point behind `redux-saga` AFAIK. You can simply use `takeEvery` (would allow multiple requests) or `takeLatest` to listen for `SELECTED_ITEM_CHANGE` action and yield to another saga that actually performs the network requests.

You can see an example right in the documentation here:
https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html

Excerpt:

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* fetchData(){
   try {
      const data = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.url)
      yield put({type: "FETCH_SUCCEEDED", data})
   } catch (error) {
      yield put({type: "FETCH_FAILED", error})
   }
}

function* watchFetchData() {
  yield takeLatest('FETCH_REQUESTED', fetchData)
}
```